# Substring - replacement

Tags: java, replace, substring

Making a game of goomba. Trying to replace the user-guessed letter with the original dashed hidden word. As the game progresses, the hidden word ( " ------- ") for example, adds dashes when it replaces the letter. Can anyone let me know where in my replace code am i going wrong?

```
if (secretWord.charAt(one)==letterGuess)
{
    System.out.println("Yes");
    System.out.println("Your guess is in the word!");
    hidden= hidden.substring(0,one) + letterGuess + hidden.substring(++one);
    System.out.println("The updated word is: "+ hidden);
    System.out.println("Guesses Remaining: " + gCount);
}
```

Comment: what is 'one'? is there a 'two', etc.? Could you paste more code?

Answer (score 1):

The code seems good to me, I pasted it into a main method:

```
public class Letterguessing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String secretWord = "hello";
        int one = 1;
        char letterGuess = 'e';
        String hidden = "-----";
        int gCount = 100;
        if (secretWord.charAt(one) == letterGuess) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
            System.out.println("Your guess is in the word!");
            hidden = hidden.substring(0, one) + letterGuess
                    + hidden.substring(++one);
            System.out.println("The updated word is: " + hidden);
            System.out.println("Guesses Remaining: " + gCount);

        }
    }

}
```

But probably you don't just want the player to guess the letter at position "1" (`secretWord.charAt(one)`) but you probably want to check all letters, if any of them matches - don't you?